# How to enable HTTP/2 on Apache (in Ubuntu 14)

Tags: 14.04, apache2

```
root@SERVER:~# ps -ef|grep -i apache|grep -v grep|awk '{print $8}'|sort -u
/usr/sbin/apache2
root@SERVER:~# dpkg -S /usr/sbin/apache2
apache2-bin: /usr/sbin/apache2
root@SERVER:~# dpkg -l | grep -w apache2-bin
ii  apache2-bin  2.4.7-1ubuntu4.13  i386  Apache HTTP Server (binary files and modules)
root@SERVER:~# 
root@SERVER:~# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
root@SERVER:~# 
root@SERVER:~# wget -q -S localhost:443 -O - 2>&1 | grep HTTP
  HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
root@SERVER:~# 
root@SERVER:~# a2enmod http2
ERROR: Module http2 does not exist!
root@SERVER:~#
```

**Question**: How can we enable HTTP/2 for our apache on Ubuntu 14?

Answer (score 0):

Considering the http2 module is considered [too experimental to be made available in **16.04**](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseNotes#HTTP.2F2_support_in_Apache_httpd), I doubt official 14.04 packages would have it available. [This Digital Ocean forum post](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/enable-http2-in-apache-on-ubuntu-16-04) suggests that [Ondřej Surý's Apache2 PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/apache2) has this feature enabled, so try that.